# Converting long hex string to binary string throws OverflowException

Tags: c#, wpf, string, binary, hex

Trying to convert a huge hex string to a binary string, but the OverflowException keeps gets thrown. This is my code to convert an image file to a hex string (which when used with a FlowDocument works perfectly!):

```
string h = new System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path)).ToString();
```

Now, however, I want to take this hex string and convert it to a binary string so that it may also displayed in FlowDocument. First, I tried writing it to a temp text file and then attempt to read it into a byte array:

```
string TempPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "Text.txt");
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(TempPath))
{
    sw.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(h, 16), 2).PadLeft(12, '0'));
}
byte[] c = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(TempPath);
```

When that didn't work, I tried reading it into a string:

```
string c = System.IO.File.ReadAll(TempPath);
```

Neither worked and still throw OverflowException. I have also tried just doing this and skipped writing to a file altogether:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(h, 16), 2).PadLeft(12, '0')
```

And despite what approach I take, I still get an exception thrown. How are large strings like this normally handled?

**Update**

I've modified my algorithm to convert one character at a time, so now it looks like this:

```
string NewBinary = "";
try
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char c in h)
    {
        if (i == 100) break;
        NewBinary = string.Concat(NewBinary, Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(12, '0'));
        i++;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the string is always going to be super long and the code above takes a LONG time to generate the binary string. I limited the length to 100 to test conversion, so the conversion itself is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert a nibble at a time using a lookup array, for example:

```
public static string HexStringToBinaryString(string hexString)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    string[] lookup =
    {
        "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
        "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
        "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
        "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
    };

    foreach (char nibble in hexString.Select(char.ToUpper))
        result.Append((nibble > '9') ? lookup[10+nibble-'A'] : lookup[nibble-'0']);

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An int64 is represented by a 16 character hex string, which is why attempting to convert a "huge string" causes an OverflowException - the value is more than can be represented by an int64. You will need to break the string up into groups of max 16 chars & convert those to binary & concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each hex character of the string into its corresponding binary pattern (eg A becomes 1010 etc)

Comment: I've add the code to do this in my original post, but it takes up a lot of time and probably isn't ideal considering the string can be super, super long. Is there a better way of doing this?